# How to create a draggable element that can be dropped as a tab onto Chrome/browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm building a web application, and would like the ability for users to:

1. drag certain objects from the page
2. drop them into the Chrome top bar
3. open the URL associated with those objects in a new tab

I'm familiar with how to build out the draggable element (and its `DataTransfer`), but not sure what the Chrome top bar is expecting in terms of MIME types. I'm not even sure the drop zones in the Chrome top bar can receive an HTML drop payload?

It'd be nice if this could be browser-agnostic, but first things first, is this even possible with Chrome?

Comment: You have no control over a drag & drop outside the current web page

Comment: I know I don't have control of the Chrome drop zones, but the theory is: the dragged payload could be configured in such a way that the Chrome drop zone would know what to do with it.

(that is how the HTML DnD API works, drop zones and draggables are decoupled, and depend only on the shared language of MIME types)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it's quite simple.

For example, try dragging and dropping this link into a new tab:

https://github.com

Here are the contents of the drag payload:

```
data: {
  "text/plain": "https://github.com/",
  "text/uri-list": "https://github.com/",
  "text/html": "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\"><a class=\"Header-link \" href=\"https://github.com/\" data-hotkey=\"g d\" aria-label=\"Homepage \" data-hydro-click=\"{&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;analytics.event&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:{&quot;category&quot;:&quot;Header&quot;,&quot;action&quot;:&quot;go to dashboard&quot;,&quot;label&quot;:&quot;icon:logo&quot;,&quot;originating_url&quot;:&quot;https://github.com/&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:16233245}}\" data-hydro-click-hmac=\"5a72d33d6c455edd8e2500d59f525e2be7a551b99712569b1ce4688db1ce7bc8\">\n  <svg class=\"octicon octicon-mark-github v-align-middle\" height=\"32\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"32\" aria-hidden=\"true\"><path fill-rule=\"evenodd\" d=\"M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0016 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z\"></path></svg>\n</a>"
}

items: [{"kind":"string","type":"text/plain"},{"kind":"string","type":"text/uri-list"},{"kind":"string","type":"text/html"}]

types: ["text/plain","text/uri-list","text/html"]
```

All you have to do is call `setData` on the `DataTransfer`, with the type `text/uri-list`, and the url you want to load on drop.